# Russia Visa process time

Tags: visas

I submitted my application in Russia embassy for private visa in new delhi, I had submitted my application on 29 April 2019 but till now it's showing under process  but on vfs website showing its  processing time 2 to 3 working days and maximum time processing time 10 working days, I don't know when ll get a my passport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, VFS is now handling Russian visas in India.

On [their website](https://www.vfsglobal.com/Russia/India/), they have a facility to track your [progress of application](https://www.vfsvisaonline.com/Global-Passporttracking/Track/Index?q=shSA0YnE4pLF9Xzwon/x/K6Wy7Ab6JP6StkE7CAk/Yr5FkI7uv1Zrc1LnMN7JKPgYpjNoEOWEvsuuL6cGsHSDA==) - you'll need your last name and Reference Number of your application.